# Twitter how to list screename of people who retweeted a (the same) tweet

Tags: json, list, api, twitter, tweets

When a tweet is tweeted how do I get the name of the people that retweeted that tweet. On Twitter you can see their profile image. But using the infos in the JSON of the tweet how can I retrieve that list of screename?

Comment: `tweet[user][screen_name]`. See https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/tweet-object.html

Comment: @Jonas you get the number of retweet but no information on who retweeted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Get the `id` of the tweet.
2. Get up to 100 retweets using `statuses/retweets` documented here https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/get-statuses-retweets-id
3. Each retweet has a `user` property which contains their `screen_name` and other info.

Comment: thanks was able to access it : responseretweetuser[0][:user][:screen_name]